# {if not isset} Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

what is the code for smarty for `if (!isset($var)){` ?

if using {if $x eq '5'} when $x is not defined in smarty , it gives an error `function call 'get_template_vars' is unknown or deprecated.` . this is what i believe so far as i lost hope in trying to know where did this error come from !

Thanky you .

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
{if ! isset($var)}
body must be at least 30 characters. :)
{/if}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `not` as in `{if not isset($var)}` [Source](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl)

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
{if $missing_var|default:FALSE}
NOT MISSING
{else}
MISSING
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
{if $var}
   Active
{else}
   Inactive
{/if}
```

Comment: what if the $var was SET and containing value of FALSE ?

Comment: if $var is not set, this will throw undefined notices in smart3.

Comment: @RamiDabain Avoid using boolean in if statements, try to use a string like $var = 'hasValue' instead if you need to do a conditional anyway. This can be a returning issue in any language you use, javascript as well.

Comment: When you have E_NOTICE activated, this solution doesn't work.